# Is there a limit to how many car and cdr we can chain in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

Some answers on here just say that you can chain multiple car and cdr to reduce the clutter they create so, you could use (cadr (list)) instead of (car (cdr (list) )), but I have tried chaining multiple car and cdr and sometimes it will stop working on like the 5th one or something, I tried googling if there is a limit or something but couldnt find any answers.

specifically my problem shows here -> trying to get 7 from a list only using car and cdr.

list is (1(2(3(4(5(6(7)))))))))

(display (car(car(cdr(car(cdr(car(cdr(car(cdr(car (cdr (car (cdr '(1(2(3(4(5(6(7)))))))))))))))))))))

-> shows 7

(display (caadadadadadadr '(1(2(3(4(5(6(7)))))))))

-> shows error

Is this not how this works?

Comment: *shows error* **What** error?

Comment: You shouldn't ordinarily need something like `caadadadadadadr`, and it's a good thing because those kinds of constructions are illegible. You might even think twice about using something legal like `cdaddr`. It's often better to write clearly named accessor functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shorthand for car and cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680068/shorthand-for-car-and-cdr)

Comment: each implementation defined by default up to a given depth, but if you need more you can define yourself.  In emacs lisp you find them in `subr.el`.

Comment: `(car(car(cdr(car(cdr(car(cdr(car(cdr(car (cdr (car (cdr ....)))))` is never used.

Comment: In my case, it's GIMP, which uses TinyScheme, and the error reads, _Error: eval: unbound variable: caaddar_  The tutorial is rather superficial about the language so I have to call in other resources.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specific about which Scheme you're using. But for every Scheme implementation I'm aware of, there's a limit to how many car/cdr compositions are provided. In [R5RS](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-reports/r5rs-html/r5rs_8.html), for example, we see

> library procedure: **cddddr** *pair*
>
> These procedures are compositions of
> `car` and `cdr`, where for example `caddr` could be defined by
>
> ```
> (define caddr (lambda (x) (car (cdr (cdr x))))).
> ```
>
> Arbitrary compositions, up to four deep, are provided. There are
> twenty-eight of these procedures in all.

Comment: And OPs example can be solved by composing them again like `(caar (cdadar (cdadar (cdadr   '(1(2(3(4(5(6(7))))))))))) ; ==> 7`

Comment: The limit is four-deep for all of R4RS, R5RS, R6RS, R7RS, and Racket.

Comment: Racket isn't Scheme and has its own tag. R5RS-reference is left unchanged in later reports so the language guarantees 4 deep. Implementations may choose to have more, but relying on that moves you away from programming Scheme to program a dialect not compatible with Scheme.